# Show that the graph $G$ is $2$ colorable

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

> Show that the graph $G$ is $2$ colorable which is define with vertex set $\mathbb Z^2$ where $(m,n)$ is adjacent to $(j,k)$ if $(m,n)\pm(1,0)=(j,k)$ or $(m,n)\pm(0,1)=(j,k)$.

I just draw a portion of the graph and it seems easily two colorable, like if I color a vertex with red and a different color (like blue) with all of it's adjacent vertices. But couldn't write it in a formal way.

[image: graph]

I was doubt to write it in plain english because there are infintely many vertices to color, it would be nice if anyone show me the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Consider whether $m+n$ is even or odd.

Comment: I see, if I just pick one color for even and another color for odd then the adjacent points in $\mathbb Z^2$ are distinguishable. Thanks @Brian M. Scott

Comment: @WhyGraph_: That’s right. You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

- Using the theorem "A graph $G$ is bipartite if and only if it does not contain an odd cycle", since the grid graph does not contain an odd length cycle (prove with induction on the length of a cycle) it's a bipartite graph. For example, the following figure shows the original graph and an isomorphic bipartite representation:

[image]

- Another theorem: "Any bipartite graph $G$ is 2-colorable" (consider $V(G) = V_1 \cup V_2$, with $E(G)=\{(u,v):u \in V_1, v \in V_2\}$. Color vertices in $V_1$ with one color and those in $V_2$ with a different color).
- Combining the above two, the grid graph is 2-colorable.
- For example, consider the off-diagonals in the grid-graph and color with alternate colors as shown in the next figure.

[image]

- In this bipartite graph the unions of the alternate diagonals create the vertex sets $V_1$ and $V_2$.

**Another way**

- Prove that the vertices on the same diagonal and also on every alternate off diagonals will be at least $\pm(1,1)$ distance away from one another, hence can't be adjacent and can be colored with the same color.

Comment: nice(+1) and detail answer. Thanks @Sandipan Dey